# FLASK RESTful API using GET to get a specific id and returning 201 using Python

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm trying to get a todo_ID using GET method. I'm still new at using sqlalchemy and most of the things i have tried are telling me that sqlalchemy doesn't use them. Also, can someone tell me how to use HEAD, i want my methods to return http statuses, i kinda tried using them and imported the render template but when i try to use them it says it has no idea what they are.

this is my attempt at looking at a tutorial and making changes

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify,json, request, render_template, abort
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('Config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class JsonModel(object):  # Class for making objects JSON serializable
    def as_dict(self):
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

class User(db.Model, JsonModel):  # Class which is a model for the User table in the database
    User_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    FirstName = db.Column(db.String(20))
    LastName = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def __init__(self,User_ID,FirstName, LastName):
        self.User_ID = User_ID
        self.FirstName = FirstName
        self.LastName = LastName

class Todo(db.Model, JsonModel):  # Class which is a model for the Todo table in the database
    todo_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.User_ID"))
    details = db.Column(db.String(30))

    def __init__(self, UserID, details):
        self.UserID = UserID
        self.details = details

@app.route('/todo', methods = ['GET'])  # Uses GET method to return all information in the database.
def index():
    return json.dumps([u.as_dict() for u in User.query.all()+Todo.query.all()]), 201

@app.route('/todo/<int:todo_ID>', methods = ['GET'])
def get(todo_ID):
    query = Todo.query.get()
    return {'todo': [dict(zip(tuple(query.keys()), i)) for i in query.cursor if i[1] == todo_ID]}


@app.before_first_request #Creates everything before the first request.
def startup():
    db.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My most recent attempt was:

```
@app.route('/todo/<int:todo_ID>', methods = ['GET'])
def get(todo_ID):
    query = Todo.query("select * from Todo")
    return {'todo': [dict(zip(tuple(query.keys()), i)) for i in query.cursor if i[1] == todo_ID]}
```

And the error that I get is this.

```
query = Todo.query("select * from Todo")
TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2016 21:15:28] "GET /todo/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: If you're selecting all **Todo** objects why don't you call **Todo.query.all()** ?

Comment: I thought that takes all of the todo objects in the database.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to filter by id, you can use Todo.query.get(id). This will query based on ID and ID should be unique so only returns one record.

Comment: you mean like id = Todo.query.get(todo_ID) and then return (id)?

Comment: I just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query Todo by *primary key* and only return **one** record you can use:

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/todo/<int:todo_ID>', methods = ['GET'])
def get(todo_ID):
    response = {}
    todo = Todo.query.get(todo_ID)
    response['id'] = todo.id
    response['user_id'] = todo.UserID
    response['details'] = todo.details
    response['status_code'] = 201
    return jsonify(response)
```

Or you can use [Marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to have a serializer for each of your models so it can serialize them for you automatically.

Comment: um it says the main_.todo object is not json serializable

Comment: thank you very much!. is there a reason why the output starts with userid first?

Comment: Not really, it's up to you. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your problem, if your intention is to return json output as response and you want to control the status code, you could
use [jsonify](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.json.jsonify)

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/todo/<int:todo_ID>', methods = ['GET'])
def get(todo_ID):
    query = Todo.query("select * from Todo")
    response = {'todo': [dict(zip(tuple(query.keys()), i)) for i in query.cursor if i[1] == todo_ID]}
    response = jsonify(response)
    response.status_code = 201
    return response
```